# Format autogenerated column in WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, datagrid

I have some data retrieved from SQLite through an SQLite Adapter that I fill into a DataTable, like this:

```
using (conexionSQLite = new SQLiteConnection(Datos.stringConexionSQLite))
{
    conexionSQLite.Open();
    string textoSQLite;
    SQLiteDataAdapter adaptadorSQLite;
    try
    {
        textoSQLite = "SELECT Fecha, ROUND(ValorTotal,0) as ValorTotal, ROUND(ValorProductoTerminado,0) as ValorProductoTerminado, ROUND(ValorSemielaborados,0) as ValorSemielaborados, ROUND(ValorMateriasPrimas,0) as ValorMateriasPrimas, ROUND(ValorEnvases,0) as ValorEnvases FROM valorStockPorFecha";
        adaptadorSQLite = new SQLiteDataAdapter(textoSQLite, conexionSQLite);
        adaptadorSQLite.Fill(bd, "tablaValorStock");
    }
    catch (SQLiteException excepcionSQL)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + excepcionSQL.ToString());
    }
}
DataTable tablaValorStock = bd.Tables["tablaValorStock"];
```

Then I bind it to a DataGrid:

```
dataGrid.ItemsSource = tablaValorStock.DefaultView;
```

That generates all the columns automatically.

**What I want is to format some of the columns**, without having to define them manually first.

I was thinking some kind of event handling of autogenerating columns, something similar to this code which is for Windows Forms' DataGrid equivalent:

```
private void RadGridView1_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, GridViewAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewDataColumn column = e.Column as GridViewDataColumn;
    if (column.DataType == typeof(int))
    {
        column.DataFormatString = "{0:p}";                             
    }
}
```

I would assing one format or another based on `DataGridColumn.Header`

Comment: Just out of interest, why are you writing this in the code behind as opposed to using the Xaml designer?

Is this a very small application whereby it isn't worth implementing the MVVM pattern?

Comment: @Hardgraf Well this is just to display some data for reading, didn't think it was worth it to create a model and a viewmodel of this structure.

Comment: I suppose it depends on how complex the application is going to become.But if you are planning CRUD functionality etc. then probably worth implementing MVVM.

Comment: @Hardgraf I mean I use MVVM in most of my app, this is just a fragment which will always be read-only, so no CRUD.

Comment: Right. Personally I would just define the datagrid in the XAML. Turn AutoGenerateColums = false & flesh out a datagrid styled to your requirements. Presumably you know what data is coming in anyway so you can define the columns yourself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this is an old post, but I met this issue recently. I post a solution here in case it helps anyone. Here is what I did in `AutoGeneratingColumn`:

```
if (e.PropertyType == typeof(int))
{
    DataGridTextColumn dataGridTextColumn = e.Column as DataGridTextColumn;
    if (dataGridTextColumn != null)
    {
        dataGridTextColumn.Binding.StringFormat = "{0:p}";
    }
 }
```

As @Hardgraf suggests, it would be much better to specify it in XAML for most of the cases. However, here is why I need this to be done in C# code. I have to display around 20 tables returned from a stored procedure. The number of the tables and the column names are totally decided by the stored procedure. It would be pretty hard to do it in XAML if possible. Even I managed to make it work in XAML, the code would be pretty hard to read. But when I do this in C# code, a simple loop and an event handler to the AutoGeneratingColumn will do the trick elegantly.